# How can I calculate the Buchstab-function with PARI/GP?

Tags: number-theory, functions, algorithms, math-software

The buchstab-function

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchstab_function

is a delayed differential equation defined as follows :

For $1\le u\le 2$ we have $\omega(u)=\frac{1}{u}$

For $u\ge 2$ we have $(u\omega(u))'=\omega(u-1)$

> How can I calculate the buchstab-function for some value $u$ numerically ?
>
> A table with some special values would also be fine.

I would like to have an algorithm working in PARI/GP or an online-calculator doing that :

I have neither Mathematica nor Matlab.

Comment: PARI/GP is incorporated into SAGE. Did you look there for an algorithm ?

Comment: No, where can I find such algorithms ?

Comment: Does a table of values from $1$ to $5$ in $0.05$ steps work?

Comment: @Moo do you have such a table ?

Comment: I can generate and post it. Of course, you can code it up in a free math program like Octave, Maxima, SAGE and many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plot of the Buchstab function is:

[image]

Below is a table of values in $0.05$ increments for $u \in [1, 6]$. Notice in the plot and data that the Buchstab function approaches ${\displaystyle e^{-\gamma }} $ rapidly as ${\displaystyle u\to \infty ,} $ , where ${\displaystyle \gamma }$  is the [*Euler–Mascheroni constant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). The numerical value is $0.5614594835668852$.

You can download a free [*Computer Algebra System*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems) or [*Octave*](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) (a free variant of Matlab) that supports routines for DDEQ and code it up. Python also has routines to support such things.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} 
 \text{u} & \text{w(u)} \\ \hline
1.&1.\\ \hline
1.05&0.952381\\ \hline
1.1&0.909091\\ \hline
1.15&0.869565\\ \hline
1.2&0.833333\\ \hline
1.25&0.8\\ \hline
1.3&0.769231\\ \hline
1.35&0.740741\\ \hline
1.4&0.714286\\ \hline
1.45&0.689655\\ \hline
1.5&0.666667\\ \hline
1.55&0.645161\\ \hline
1.6&0.625\\ \hline
1.65&0.606061\\ \hline
1.7&0.588235\\ \hline
1.75&0.571429\\ \hline
1.8&0.555556\\ \hline
1.85&0.540541\\ \hline
1.9&0.526316\\ \hline
1.95&0.512821\\ \hline
2.&0.5\\ \hline
2.05&0.511605\\ \hline
2.1&0.521576\\ \hline
2.15&0.530122\\ \hline
2.2&0.537419\\ \hline
2.25&0.543619\\ \hline
2.3&0.548854\\ \hline
2.35&0.553236\\ \hline
2.4&0.556863\\ \hline
2.45&0.559822\\ \hline
2.5&0.562186\\ \hline
2.55&0.564022\\ \hline
2.6&0.565386\\ \hline
2.65&0.56633\\ \hline
2.7&0.566899\\ \hline
2.75&0.567133\\ \hline
2.8&0.567067\\ \hline
2.85&0.566732\\ \hline
2.9&0.566157\\ \hline
2.95&0.565366\\ \hline
3.&0.564382\\ \hline
3.05&0.563424\\ \hline
3.1&0.562671\\ \hline
3.15&0.562088\\ \hline
3.2&0.561647\\ \hline
3.25&0.561324\\ \hline
3.3&0.561096\\ \hline
3.35&0.560947\\ \hline
3.4&0.560861\\ \hline
3.45&0.560826\\ \hline
3.5&0.560829\\ \hline
3.55&0.560861\\ \hline
3.6&0.560915\\ \hline
3.65&0.560984\\ \hline
3.7&0.56106\\ \hline
3.75&0.56114\\ \hline
3.8&0.561219\\ \hline
3.85&0.561293\\ \hline
3.9&0.561359\\ \hline
3.95&0.561415\\ \hline
4.&0.561458\\ \hline
4.05&0.561488\\ \hline
4.1&0.561507\\ \hline
4.15&0.561517\\ \hline
4.2&0.561521\\ \hline
4.25&0.561521\\ \hline
4.3&0.561517\\ \hline
4.35&0.561511\\ \hline
4.4&0.561504\\ \hline
4.45&0.561497\\ \hline
4.5&0.56149\\ \hline
4.55&0.561482\\ \hline
4.6&0.561476\\ \hline
4.65&0.56147\\ \hline
4.7&0.561466\\ \hline
4.75&0.561462\\ \hline
4.8&0.561459\\ \hline
4.85&0.561457\\ \hline
4.9&0.561455\\ \hline
4.95&0.561455\\ \hline
5.&0.561454\\ \hline
5.05&0.561455\\ \hline
5.1&0.561455\\ \hline
5.15&0.561456\\ \hline
5.2&0.561456\\ \hline
5.25&0.561457\\ \hline
5.3&0.561457\\ \hline
5.35&0.561458\\ \hline
5.4&0.561458\\ \hline
5.45&0.561459\\ \hline
5.5&0.561459\\ \hline
5.55&0.561459\\ \hline
5.6&0.56146\\ \hline
5.65&0.56146\\ \hline
5.7&0.56146\\ \hline
5.75&0.56146\\ \hline
5.8&0.56146\\ \hline
5.85&0.56146\\ \hline
5.9&0.56146\\ \hline
5.95&0.56146\\ \hline
6.&0.56146\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: What can you tell me about "Octave" ? Do I have to download it ? How powerful is it ? etc.

Comment: I included a link. It is basically a free version of Matlab and is very powerful. I haven't used it much, but it is excellent and if you are looking for something that can basically run Matlab code, this is the tool. Yes, you can download it (it is open source and free), install on your platform and then mess around with code examples - including getting code and taking it for a spin.